# Can I disable software restriction policy windows xp?

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I am using windows xp pro and i am trying to install a chess game my friend build. Eveytime i try to install i get the message:

> "windows can't open this program since it has been block by software
>   restriction policy. For more information, open the event viewer or
>   contact the system administrator".

Since i am the system administrator it is a weird problem to have.
I have opened secpol.msc to look at the Software Restrictions folder. When i choose the folder on the left pane it says that i don't have a Software Restrictions policy configured...

Any ideas on what to do?

Comment: What is in the event viewer?

Comment: have you tried "Run As"

Answer (score 0):

I posted the question before i registered and now i can't see how to answer the comments without posting in the answer section.

In the event viewer there is nothing about the message.
I have tried "Run As" and got the same result.